# Get the latest record in a table using two fields as an identifier

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find the latest order that is put in for a shop for a specific location in a shop. Therefore each shop has multiple orders to a location inside the shop.

**Here is my table:**

```
LocationId  StoreId OrderStreet     OrderCity   PCode   OrderState      OrderDate          
37          494     Store           Store       3000    NT              11/13/2013 2:43:04 PM
38          494     Store           Store       3000    NSW             12/04/2013 11:32
41          496     Underword       Narrabeen   2100    NSW             12/04/2013 11:37
38          494     Store           Store       3000    NT              12/09/2013 10:47
38          494     Store           Store       3000    NT              12/09/2013 10:51
40          496     Underword       Narrabeen   2100    NSW             3/03/2014 8:5
42          497     345 Malltomall  Sydney      3999    NSW             4/01/2014 15:17
42          497     345 Malltomall  Sydney      3999    NSW             4/01/2014 16:58 92
41          496     Underword       Narrabeen   2100    NSW             4/01/2014 17:14
43          497     345 Malltomall  Sydney      3999    NSW             4/02/2014 15:21
```

**Here is what i have done so far:** 
This gives me the latest order for each shop, but only returns 1 single location for each shop.

```
SELECT        A.OrderDate, A.OrderId, A.StoreId, A.LocationId, A.OrderStreet, A.OrderCity, A.OrderState, A.OrderPostCode, A.StoreId + A.LocationId AS Sum1
FROM            tblOrder AS A INNER JOIN
                              (SELECT   StoreId, MAX(OrderDate) AS MaxDate
                              FROM     tblOrder
                              GROUP BY StoreId) AS B 
                              ON A.StoreId = B.StoreId AND A.OrderDate = B.MaxDate
```

**Here is what it returns:**
I thought i could add the columns together to get a unique code eg. **Sum1** but I could not get it to work.

```
Orderdate     StoreId  LocationId OrderStreet       OrderCity   OrderState  Pcode   Sum1
4/02/2014     497      43         345 Malltomall    Sydney      NSW         3999    540
4/01/2014     496      41         Underword         Narrabeen   NSW         2100    537
12/09/2013    494      38         Store             Store       NT          3000    532
```

**God i feel dumb...**

Answer (score 0):

Group the derived table by `LocationId` *as well as* `StoreId`, then join back to the original table on that column too.  I think that queries for groupwise maxima, like this, are a perfect use case for `NATURAL JOIN` (which is more concise as it does not require an explicit predicate, instead joining on all columns having the same name in both tables):

```
SELECT * FROM tblOrder NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT   StoreId, LocationId, MAX(OrderDate) AS OrderDate
  FROM     tblOrder
  GROUP BY StoreId, LocationId
) t
```

Alternatively, if `LocationId` is unique across all stores, you could merely group/join on that column (and entirely remove `StoreId` from the derived table):

```
SELECT * FROM tblOrder NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT   LocationId, MAX(OrderDate) AS OrderDate
  FROM     tblOrder
  GROUP BY LocationId
) t
```